# Add window closing confirmation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I need some help. I have started a HND in Computing they are using visual studios 2012 and we have to make applications using WPF and c#. I am really struggling and falling behind because I can't do some of the simplest things.

The windows form has not x or minus button in visual studios but when u run the applicaiton it is there.

I want to create a simple  Are you sure option when clicking on the x button.

I can't see how i access in VS2012 C# wpf applications.

It used to be in the property

I could really use some pointing in the right direction.

Are WPF, C# and visual studios all individual identiys? It seems to me for 2012 microsoft have had a brain transplant

Comment: How about first reading one or two books about .NET/C# programming, followed by one or two about WPF, before asking questions here?

Comment: Chill out dude, I am a student. Money isn't a thing luxury you know! 
I am learning as fast as I can. 

My lecture I agree isn't presenting c# in an easy to follow way for people who heave never done it before. 

I can't afford to fail this course I am doing all the reasearch I can in my spare time but with 2 kids and wife thats not a lot of time.

Sorry, I thought this was a place for people to get help not get shouted at for not being an expert!!

Comment: I am not shouting at you for not being an expert. But honestly, you can't learn this without reading a few chapters about the basics...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) event and cancel it via a property in the event arguments. How you subscribe to the event is up to you, if you want to use the IDE consult its help about events or search online, it can all be done manually [in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) as well.

Comment: I got it, Its a visual studio 2012 thing. 

there are 2 itcons the spanar and lighting bolt. This feature is under the thunderbolt icon.

TO get the coding i just double click..

Comment: I think its because of the WPF. 

I havn't used visual studios for a long time. 

It took me 24 hours to work out just how to change the background image of the window or (Form) as i know it. 

I am not a designer I have worked out that Xaml is for desiners and anything to do with design is found there. 

But as you u say the seration is alien to me. I am struggling to find where all theses elements now exist

Comment: @AlanAuckland: You don't need it. All the IDE does can be done in code. I never use any of those features, i write XAML and C# manually. The IDE is just generating code, it's useless if you don't know what it does or what you have to click to get what you want.

Comment: I am doing a HND in Computing and C# and wpf are new to me. 
I have been given work sheets that are not very informative. they give you a screenshot of the form and some c# and xaml code fragments and then its up to you to reaserch and fill in the gaps. 
When it comes to web development I am top of the class but this i struggling with I dont know where to find. And the lectures instrucitons like when he says create a function that does this
When i then resaerch funcion c# i get nothing !! because i think c# no longer knows what a function is in the old sense. so my previous understanding is NA